# Why is a local variable used in this String class method?

Tags: java, performance

In the [Java 11 String's hashCode](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#L1501-L1508) method a local integer variable "h" is used to store the hash field's value.

Is this done for performance reasons, or a mere stylistic choice? [An answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67098831/18140249) says it's for thread safety, but Strings are immutable so it doesn't seem the case

Comment: I reopened the question, because the [duplicated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576939/java-string-hashcode-caching) does not answer this particular question, which is about the use of the local variable `h`.

Comment: Well if there is an reassignment to the non-final field ```hash``` within the ```hashCode``` method, then String is not immutable enough. That's why they changed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The git blame for that method refers to [JDK-8166842](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8166842).

From that issue, the reasoning was

> Latest change to JDK 9 String code introduced a non-benign data race:
>
> ```java
> public int hashCode() {
>    if (hash == 0 && value.length > 0) {
>        hash = isLatin1() ? StringLatin1.hashCode(value)
>                          : StringUTF16.hashCode(value);
>    }
>    return hash;
> }
> ```
>
> The 'hash' field should only be read once into a local variable. The second racy read (at return) can read 0 while the 1st (at if) can read non-zero.

Comment: Good example to attend for a "pure function" that should return merely a value without side-effects and for performance reason, change inner state of the object.

Comment: How's possible that the first hash is non-zero but the second one is? If I understood correcly only a non-zero value may be assigned to hash, so the worst case seems to be simply calculating the hash more than once

Comment: It's a good question and I'm not really sure of the mechanics of it. It's also worth noting that the hashCode method [has changed again](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk13u/blob/8da90d672369a305b1dd7ad7cad0110a8d683d40/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#L1536) since the `h` variable was added to include a `hashIsZero` field to avoid recalculating 0 hashes.

Comment: Because the memory model allows the 2 reads to be reordered, which means that the second read can actually happen before the first one.

Answer (score 0):

While Holloway has answered the question itself, I'd like to clear up a minor misconception.

`String` is only immutable in the sense that it doesn't expose functionality for mutating it. However, it still does have an *internal* mutable state, specifically the `hash` field.

Calculating the hash of a `String` is a relatively simple O(n) operation. Not disastrous, but also not completely free, especially not for longer strings.

Since strings are a fundamental part of almost all aspects of Java and used basically everywhere, including in Java-internal functionality, ensuring good performance for the implementation of `String` is critical. Even a minor inefficiency may be enormously multiplied simply from how incredibly often it gets run. As such, while the hash calculation isn't too bad, it's still something we'd like to *not have to do* unless it's absolutely necessary.

Now, there are three ways we could go about calculating the hash:

1. We calculate it every time `hashCode()` is called. In other words, we only calculate it when we need it. However, that also means we have to *recalculate* it every single time it's needed. This would be disastrous for `HashMap` and similar.
2. Calculate it *once* when we create the string, then return the same value every time `hashCode()` is called. This makes `hashCode()` free, but makes the creation of a string more expensive for the situations where the hash isn't needed. Since *a lot* of strings are constantly created in Java, that's a non-negligible.
3. We do it *lazily*, i.e. we calculate it the first time `hashCode()` is called and then remember it for subsequent calls to `hashCode()`.

The latter option was chosen since it finds that sweet spot between "don't calculate it unless you need it" and "don't calculate it more than once". This *does* mean that `String` has a mutable state; it updates its internal cache of the hash code. However, from an outside observer, this effect is invisible (aside from the fact that the first call to `hashCode()` is slightly slower), meaning that the string is *effectively* immutable.